# Interpolate elevations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I'm quite new to QGIS and I have a problem. I have a set of points in CSV format with X,Y,Z coordinates which I want to import in QGIS. Then I have another set of points with X,Y,0 coordinates, which means I have no elevation in the second set. Is there a possibility to interpolate the elevation of the second set and export it to any format?

Comment: Interpolate... based on what exactly? Can you provide more information/screenshot/sample data about the distribution of your points etc.?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert your XYZ data to a raster and then add the raster values to the second set of points?

Comment: Interpolate, drape